# R Shiny ggplot2 Support Vector Machine Trend Line

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, svm

I have been frustrated by this for ages; I cannot get the trend line to appear:

```
library(shiny)
ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Twitter Engagement Correlations"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("c", label = "Variable:",
                     choices = colnames(dataset))
      ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {

  reactive({
    library(e1071)
    regressor = svm(Engagements ~ Character.count, 
                    data = dataset,
                    type = 'eps-regression')
  })

  output$plot1 = renderPlot({
    print(ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x = dataset[,input$c], y = dataset$Engagements),
                 colour = 'red') +
        geom_line(aes(x = dataset$Character.count, y = predict(regressor, newdata = dataset)),
                  colour = 'blue') +
      ggtitle('SVR Regression Model') +
      xlab(input$c) +
      ylab('Engagements'))
    })
}
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The error code 'object 'regressor' not found' appears and I don't know how to solve this? 
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `regressor` variable is not defined inside the scope of `plot1`. You need to name your `reactive`:

```
getRegressor <- reactive({
   library(e1071)
   svm(Engagements ~ Character.count, 
               data = dataset,
               type = 'eps-regression')
 })
```

Now you can call it to define the variable `regressor` **inside** `plot1`:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  regressor <- getRegressor()
  ...
})
```